# SolvePnP giving OpenCV Error: Assertion failed

Tags: opencv

getting error:

> (-215) npoints >= 0 && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2,
>   CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F))

in function solvePnP , while running the loop.

This is the part of my code.When I run it runs perfectly for sometime and throws the above error. I tried to manage this by using flag to remove this but it gives an error after sometime rather than giving instantaneously.
Please help me to find the solution for this problem.

Pose.h

```
 #ifndef POSE_H
 #define POSE_H

 #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
 #include <cv.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


  using namespace std;
  using namespace cv;

  class Pose
  {
  public:
  Pose();

  double* contour_detection(Mat threshold,Mat src);
  double* pose_estimation(const std::vector<cv::Point3f> &objectPoints,const std::vector<cv::Point2f> &imagePoints);
  private:
  vector<Point3f> objectPoints ;
  Mat  cameraIntrinsicParams ;
  Mat distCoeffs;


  };
#endif // POSE_H
```

Pose.cpp

```
#include "Pose.h"
Pose::Pose()
{

objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3f(240.f,680.f,715.f));
objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3f(240.f,680.f,215.f));
objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3f(615.f,680.f,215.f));
objectPoints.push_back(cv::Point3f(615.f,680.f,715.f));

cameraIntrinsicParams=Mat(Size(3,3),CV_32FC1);       
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(0,0)=  727.957294f;
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(0,1)= 0 ;
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(0,2)= 320.f;//304.729528f;
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(1,0)= 0 ;
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(1,1)=  726.232798f;
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(1,2)= 240.f;//235.217420f;
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(2,0)= 0 ;
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(2,1)= 0 ;
cameraIntrinsicParams.at<float>(2,2)= 1 ;


distCoeffs=Mat::zeros(Size(4,1),CV_64FC1); 

}

double* Pose::contour_detection(Mat threshold, Mat src)
{
 int flag =0;
 int largest_area=0;
 int largest_contour_index;
 int lowThreshold;
 int ratio=3;
 int kernel_size=3;
 int const max_lowThreshold = 100;

 vector<Point>Points ;
 vector< vector<Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
 vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
 Mat detected_edges;
 blur(threshold, detected_edges, Size(3,3) );

 /// Canny detector
 Canny( detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold,lowThreshold*ratio,  kernel_size );
 vector< vector<Point> > contours0;
 findContours( detected_edges, contours0, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // Find the contours in the image

 contours.resize(contours0.size());
 std::vector<Point2f> imagePoints;
 std::vector<Point2f> preciseCorners(4);
 for( size_t k = 0; k < contours0.size(); k++ )
    {
      double a=contourArea( contours0[k],false); // Find the area of contour
    if(a>largest_area)
        {
    largest_area=a;
        largest_contour_index=k ;
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours0[largest_contour_index]), contours[largest_contour_index],9, true);
        if(contours[k].size()==4)
        {

    for (int c=0;c<4;c++)
    {       
    preciseCorners[c] = contours[largest_contour_index][c];
    }

    cv::cornerSubPix(threshold, preciseCorners, cvSize(5,5),cvSize(-1,-1),  TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 40, 0.001 ));
          //  cv::cornerSubPix(threshold, preciseCorners, cvSize(5,5),cvSize(-1,-1), cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,30,0.1));

    for (int c=0;c<4;c++)
    {
    contours[largest_contour_index][c] = preciseCorners[c];
    }

         imagePoints.push_back(Point2f(contours[largest_contour_index][0].x,contours[largest_contour_index][0].y));
        imagePoints.push_back(Point2f(contours[largest_contour_index][1].x,contours[largest_contour_index][1].y));
        imagePoints.push_back(Point2f(contours[largest_contour_index][2].x,contours[largest_contour_index][2].y));
        imagePoints.push_back(Point2f(contours[largest_contour_index][3].x,contours[largest_contour_index][3].y));

  Point P1=contours[largest_contour_index][0];
  Point P2=contours[largest_contour_index][1];
  Point P3=contours[largest_contour_index][2];
  Point P4=contours[largest_contour_index][3];

  line(src,P1,P2, Scalar(0,255,0),1,CV_AA,0);
  line(src,P2,P3, Scalar(0,255,0),1,CV_AA,0);
  line(src,P3,P4, Scalar(0,255,0),1,CV_AA,0);
  line(src,P4,P1, Scalar(0,255,0),1,CV_AA,0);

  flag =1;
        }
        }
  }
  // Pose estimation. 

    if(flag==1)
    {
        double *location=pose_estimation(objectPoints,imagePoints);
        flag =0;
        return location;
        }


    }

    double* Pose::pose_estimation(const std::vector<cv::Point3f> &objectPoints,const std::vector<cv::Point2f> &imagePoints)
    {

    static double position[4];

    Mat rvec,tvec;            
    bool useExtrinsicGuess = false;     

   int method =CV_ITERATIVE;
   cv::solvePnP(objectPoints,imagePoints, cameraIntrinsicParams, distCoeffs,rvec, tvec,useExtrinsicGuess,method);

    Mat distant=Mat(Size(3,3),CV_64FC1);
    Mat jacobian=Mat(Size(3,1),CV_32FC1);
    Rodrigues(rvec,distant,jacobian);

    Mat J;
    vector<Point2f> p(4);
    projectPoints(objectPoints,rvec,tvec, cameraIntrinsicParams,  distCoeffs, p, J);

    float sum = 0.;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <p.size(); i++)
     {
      sum += sqrt((p[i].x - imagePoints[i].x)* (p[i].x - imagePoints[i].x)+(p[i].y - imagePoints[i].y)* (p[i].y - imagePoints[i].y));
     }

    Mat R= distant.t();         

           cout << "sum=" << sum << endl;
           Mat T = -R * tvec ;
           position[0] =T.at<double>(0,0);
           position[1]=T.at<double>(1,0);
           position[2]=T.at<double>(2,0);

    return position;
    }
```